# Set the localstorage.getItem() value on the stopwatch in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a stopwatch that will work in the background.

When I run the clock I set it in localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem ('timerOn', true);

localStorage.setItem ('timerTime', Date.now () - this.state.timerTime)
```

When I stop the clock set in localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem ('timerOn', false);

localStorage.setItem ('timerTime', Date.now () + this.state.timerTime);
```

I have a problem with resetting these values on the clock:

```
LocalStorage.getItem ('timerOn')

LocalStorage.getItem ('timerTime')
```

Can someone advise something?
How do you do that if I close the browser, then this stopwatch will work?

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jj7jef

```
class Stopwatch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }


  startTimer = () => {
    const { timerOn, timerTime, timerStart } = this.state;


    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);

    localStorage.setItem('timerOn', true);
    localStorage.setItem('timerTime', Date.now() -       this.state.timerTime)
};

stopTimer = () => {
  this.setState({ timerOn: false });
  localStorage.setItem('timerOn', false);
  localStorage.setItem('timerTime', Date.now() +    
   this.state.timerTime);
  clearInterval(this.timer);
};

  render() {
    const { timerTime } = this.state;
    let centiseconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
    let seconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
    let minutes = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
    let hours = ("0" + Math.floor(timerTime / 3600000)).slice(-2);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Stopwatch-display">
          {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds} 
        </div>

        {(
          <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
        )}

        {this.state.timerOn === true && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
          <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to start from the same time last stopped when opening the browser?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings  When I stopped stopwatch I want to run from the same time;  
When the clock is running it wants it to count even when the browser is closed

Comment: That is not possible. JavaScript on your page can run only when your page is loaded. Your best bet is service workers, but browsers would terminate them when detecting an infinite loop

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings  And how to do it as the browser is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

In localStorage setItem you must do like that

`localStorage.setItem('Item name', JSON.stringify(item));`

Then in get Method

`let x = await localStorage.getItem('Item name');
 let y = JSON.parse(x);
 console.log(y);`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the functionality as mentioned below:

- If the clock is running and closed the window and reponed later it will be still counting.
- If we stop the clock and start again it will start from current time.
- If we stop the clock and closed window, reponed again It will show the last count time, you can start from there.

You can also add a reset button if needed.

```
class Stopwatch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let timerOn = localStorage.getItem('timerOn') === "true";
    let timerStart = localStorage.getItem('timerStart')
    let timerTime = localStorage.getItem('timerTime')

    await this.setState({
      timerOn: timerOn,
      timerStart: timerStart,
      timerTime: timerTime
    });

    if (timerOn) {
      this.startTimer()
    }
  }


  startTimer = (e) => {
    let { timerOn, timerTime = 0, timerStart = 0 } = this.state;

    if (e && timerOn) {
      return // stop continuous start button click
    }

    if (!timerOn) {
      // stop / pause state
      // start / resume from current time
      timerStart = Date.now() - timerTime
    }
    else if (timerOn) {
      // running state
      // calculate and compensate closed time
      timerTime = Date.now() - timerStart
    }

    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: timerTime,
      timerStart: timerStart
    });

    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - timerStart
      });
    }, 10);

    localStorage.setItem('timerOn', true);
    localStorage.setItem('timerStart', timerStart)
    localStorage.removeItem("timerTime")
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    localStorage.setItem('timerOn', false);
    localStorage.setItem('timerTime', this.state.timerTime);
    localStorage.removeItem("timerStart")
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  render() {
    const { timerTime = 0 } = this.state;
    let centiseconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
    let seconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
    let minutes = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
    let hours = ("0" + Math.floor(timerTime / 3600000)).slice(-2);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Stopwatch-display">
          {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds}
        </div>

        {(
          <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
        )}

        {this.state.timerOn === true && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
          <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(<Stopwatch />, document.getElementById('root'));
```